# Is it possible to use ExactTarget with client-side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, exacttarget

I'm wondering, Is ther any way to use ExactTarget (XML API) with client-side JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not want to use ExactTarget's XML API using client-side JavaScript for security reasons since the user credentials are part of the payload.